# Htaccess to clearn url without should the file base

Tags: .htaccess, clean-urls

I have the below line in my htaccess file to clean url and is working very fine but i want to redirect to a page without showing the base file name.

What the code does `http://example.com/index/e/dog`
What am trying to do is to hide the index.php and have a url like this
`http://example.com/e/dog`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php  [L,QSA] #remove php extension

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?e=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index/e/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index/e/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?e=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Unclean url `http://example.com/index.php?e=dog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make sure you are linking to `/e/dog` in your application, and not `/index/e/dog`. You then basically just need to remove `index` from your directives. There's also no need for your initial directive that appends the `.php` extension.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

# This is optional and only serves to redirect users and search engines
# that have already linked to / indexed the old URL structure.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?e=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /e/%1? [R=302,L]

# Rewrite URL to actual filesystem path
RewriteRule ^e/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?e=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) only when you are sure it's working OK. This is to avoid problems of 301s being cached by the browser.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.